# Alert displaying only parts of arguments

Tags: javascript

Here is a snippet/html of my work.

```js
<script language="javascript">

var imagesArray = [
'images/img-1.jpg',
'images/img-2.jpg',
'images/img-3.jpg',
'images/img-4.jpg',
'images/img-5.jpg',
'images/img-6.jpg',
'images/img-7.jpg'
];

var usedImages = {};
var usedImagesCount = 0;
var score = 0;

function displayImage(){

    var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * (imagesArray.length));
    if (!usedImages[num]){
        document.canvas.src = imagesArray[num];
        usedImages[num] = true;
        usedImagesCount++;
        if (usedImagesCount === imagesArray.length){
            usedImagesCount = 0;
            usedImages = {};
        }
    } else {
        displayImage();
    }
}

function check(){
 x = prompt('What is the movie title?');
 var y;
 if (document.canvas.src=='images/img-1.jpg'){
  y = 'The Expandables';}
 if (document.canvas.src=='images/img-2.jpg'){
  y = 'License to Wed';}
 if (document.canvas.src=='images/img-3.jpg'){
  y = "Schindler's List";}
 if (document.canvas.src=='images/img-4.jpg'){
  y = 'The Heartbreak Kid';}
 if (document.canvas.src=='images/img-5.jpg'){
  y = 'The Interview';}
 if (document.canvas.src=='images/img-6.jpg'){
  y = 'How To Train Your Dragon 2';}
 if (document.canvas.src=='images/img-7.jpg'){
  y = 'Avatar';}
 if (y == x){
  score = score + 10;
  alert('Your points is ', score ,'.');}
 else{
  score = score;
  alert('Your points is ', score ,'.')}
  
 
 var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * (imagesArray.length));
    if (!usedImages[num]){
        document.canvas.src = imagesArray[num];
        usedImages[num] = true;
        usedImagesCount++;
        if (usedImagesCount === imagesArray.length){
            usedImagesCount = 0;
            usedImages = {};
        }
    } else {
        displayImage();
    }
 
}
</script>
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<form name="imageForm">
  <table border=3>
   <tr align="center">
    <td>
      <input onclick="displayImage();" type=button value="Start!">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src="blank.jpg" name="canvas" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  </table>
 <input onclick="check();" type=button value="Answer!">
</form>
 </body>
</html>
```

When I run the JScript:
The output is OK except that the JScript alert is:

> Your points is

regardless if my answer was right or wrong.

Why doesn't it display the score? What was my mistake?

Answer (score 1):

You can concatenate strings using `+`, not using `,`:

```
alert('Your score is ' + score + '.');
```

Comment: However, it always show that my points is still 0 no matter what my answer was true/false.

Comment: @KennethLigutom Should not happen unless your comparison (`y == x`) fails. Add some debugging output to test whether that comparison works.

Comment: Should give it a try. However, if the title is true, it shows: "Your points is 0".

Comment: Can you please help? I don't know. (P.S.) I'm a beginner in JScript

Comment: You can find a [working fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/m2o8cj2o/1/). Note that I don't have the pictures so I used the `title` attribute, hover over the image to see which picture should be shown. Pay attention: Your code requires you to enter the answer exactly as it is in you code.

Comment: Shall give it a try. Thanks!! THAT WORKED!!